# 4r03 error on phpMyAdmin when change root user name to dlb123 but can get access to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am on Windows 10 trying to use apache to run wordpress on a local system for development and testing.

I first changed root password, then change the root username to (example) dbo123 using mysql commands. I can login to mysql with my new username and password just fine. I could log in to phpMyAdmin fine after I changed password, but then get 403 errors after changing username.

I deleted all browser history, and rebooted system but still getting 403 Access Denied.

I changed config.inc.phy to (not using real username and password but example)

```
/* Authentication type and info */
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'dbo123';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Stuf34$';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

Any help?

Comment: I don't think if this 403 error have anything with username or password, but as you could login before, I don't really know ! did you changed any other config file ? did your IP address changed recently ? maybe PMA is not configured to receive connection from your IP.